# How to write a destructor for a class which includes a map<int,*double> member?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class like:

```
class CPR_data{
public:
    /*some functions*/
private:
    map<int,double*> data;    //saving data
};
```

In the file `main.cpp`, I add data into the class as following:

```
double *data_ = new double[n_var];
auto insert_flag = data.insert(make_pair(n,data_));
```

I used the default destructor but it seems a Memory Leak. Do I need to delete all the arrays manually in the destructor?

Comment: Simple; replace the `double*` with a `std::vector<double>`, and you won't need to write anything.

Comment: suggestion: avoid direct new/delete managment but (you're using C++11) use smart pointers

Comment: If your class doesnt `new` the data it is also not its responsibility to delete it. If main calls `new` also main should call `delete` or even better nobody calls `new` and everybody is happy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You loop through your map and call `delete[]` on every element.

```
~CPR_data()
{
  for(auto& elem : data)
  {
    delete[] elem.second;
  }
}
```

Note that you now also have to write your own copy constructor and copy assignment operator.

---

However, the *real* solution is to use `std::map<int, std::vector<double>>` instead so you won't have to do any bookkeeping and any questioning about who owns what pointer etc. There's a good chance it'll be as fast as your dynamic allocation method.

You really shouldn't be using any dynamic allocation in C++11 since everything nowadays has a better alternative unless you're writing a standard library implementation or some other exotic piece of code.

Comment: Not just copy c'tor. An assignment operator as well. And the rvalue variants of those need to be explicitly defaulted. So inconvenient...

Comment: @StoryTeller Whenever I say "copy xx" I actually mean con and assignment, I always forget to add that one, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<int, vector<double>> data;
    vector<double> data_ = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };
    auto insert_flag = data.insert(make_pair(1, data_));
    vector<double> data_2 = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 };
    insert_flag = data.insert(make_pair(2, data_2));
    for(const auto& val : data[2])
        cout << val << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to implement **your own** destructor just for that case. The only thing you have to ensure is to make the `double*` get deleted when your object is destroyed.

Implementing a destructor that will run through all items is one option, but you can also (as others said) switch to using some other element type. vector is one option, but surely that's not an array.

If you need to stick with raw dynamic arrays, you can always wrap the raw pointer into a smart pointer that will keep track of it and will delete it appropriately.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <boost/scoped_array.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::map<int,boost::scoped_array<double>> data;

    int n = 250;
    double* data_ = new double[n]; // POTENTIAL LEAK
    data_[249] = -1;               // POTENTIAL LEAK
    /* ... */                      // POTENTIAL LEAK

    auto insert_flag = data.insert(std::make_pair(n,data_));

    std::cout << insert_flag.first->first << " " << insert_flag.second << std::endl;
    std::cout << data[250][249] << std::endl;
}
```

Please be careful with smart pointer type - here I'm using `scoped_array` as opposed to typical `scoped_ptr` which is appropriate only for pointers to single object. For dynamic arrays, `scoped_array` is needed.

Nevertheless, as you can see above, using smart pointer is very similar to using raw pointer. Smart pointers were designed to be as much similar in use as possible. They come with their own destructors, so when the (default) destructor of your object kicks in, it destroys the map, which in turn destroys its elements - and now the elements are smart-pointer - so they will deallocate the arrays.

Actually, I still would encourage you to use `vector` or whatever else than raw pointers. With raw dynamic allocations you have to be **extra careful** because even in my example above, there is a tiny possibility of a memory leak - if anything interrupts the code (i.e. exception) between `new`'ing the raw pointer and packing the pointer into scoped one - nothing will deallocate the raw dynamic array. For that reason, it's best to wrap them as soon as possible and ensure, as hard as it can be, that nothing can interrupt the flow before the raw pointer starts being managed by smart pointer object.

And, as last line - be sure to check out the difference between `scoped` and `shared` smart pointers. I used `scoped` here, because it seems fit. However, it's worth knowing about both types.